# CSS select element which has a following element

Tags: html, css-selectors

I was trying to select The first element of 2 Folloing elements, and I am not allowed to change the HTML :( 

For Exampe:

```
span + span {
 border: red solid 1px;
}
<span>I wanna select this</span>
<span>not this</span>
<br>
<span>not this</span>
<br>
<span>I wanna select this</span>
<span>not this</span>
```

I know I can get the second span like this `"span + span"`
but is there a way to get the first Element?

Comment: _“but is there a way to get the first Element?”_ - no, there is not. You can select elements based on that they come _after_ other elements, but not the other way around.

Comment: So at most you can apply some workarounds, to try and achieve the desired effect. In some situation, one can format _all_ elements one way, and then revert/overwrite that formatting for the “unwanted” elements, based on that they do come after the wanted ones, or something like that. (Although in your specific situation here, that would be hard to do as well. Ritika Gupta’s current answer might work for the specific situation, but if there is anything more “dynamic” going on, it might fail again.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are two elements in the container, then the 1st of them is the first child and the second last child of its parent. Thus, to select only first children of such containers, you can use the following selector:

`span:first-child:nth-last-child(2) { ... }`

Comment: I didn't see update to your question when I wrote the answer, so I assumed that pairs of `span`s to select the 1st item from are wrapped together with some kind of a common container. With the HTML structure you posted in the update, there is no such easy solution. Isn't it possible to wrap lines of text with `<p>`s or `<div>`s instead of separating them with `<br>`s?

Answer (score 1):

Please Check if this serves your purpose.

```css
span:first-of-type{
border: 1px solid red;
}
.line-break + span:nth-of-type(2n){
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span>I wanna select this</span>
<span>not this</span>
<br class="line-break">
<span>not this</span>
<br class="line-break">
<span>I wanna select this</span>
<span>not this</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with parent and use selector like that

```
.example span:first-child{}
```

Comment: Or even more basic: `html span:first-child`